# C++ Newbie - Header Redefinition Errors, Linking Errors

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors, header-files

I'm very new to C++, I'm trying to get some university work done. I'm building my C++ program in Visual Studio 2010. I've poured over the code, and can't figure out why it isn't working. The following is all the code in my project. Sorry that I had to post it all, but I don't know where the problem lies.

employee.h

```
#ifndef EMPLOYEE_H
#define EMPLOYEE_H
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Employee
{
public:
    int empNumber;

    string getName();
    int getId();
    float getBaseSalary();
    virtual string getTitle();
    virtual int getNumTaskCompleted();
    virtual float getGrossSalary();
    virtual float getBonus();
    virtual void setEmployeeDetails();
};
#endif
```

employee.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Employee
{
private:
    string name;
    int id;
    float salary;

public:
    string getName()
    {
        return this->name;
    }

    int getId()
    {
        return this->id;
    }

    float getBaseSalary()
    {
        return this->salary;
    }

    void setEmployeeDetails()
    {
        cout << "Enter employee name (no spaces): ";
        cin >> this->name;
        cout << "Enter employee id (numeric): ";
        cin >> this->id;
        cout << "Enter employee salary: ";
        cin >> this->salary;
    }
};
```

projectManager.h

```
#ifndef PROJECT_MANAGER_H
#define PROJECT_MANAGER_H
#include <string>
#include "employee.h"

using namespace std;

class ProjectManager : public Employee
{
public:
    string getTitle();
    int getNumTaskCompleted();
    float getGrossSalary();
    float getBonus();
    void setBonus(float bonus);
    void setEmployeeDetails();
};
#endif
```

projectManager.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "employee.h"

using namespace std;

class ProjectManager : public Employee
{
private:
    int numTaskCompleted;
    float bonus;

public:
    string getTitle()
    {
        return "Manager";
    }

    int getNumTaskCompleted()
    {
        return this->numTaskCompleted;
    }

    float getGrossSalary()
    {
        return this->getBaseSalary() + this->bonus;
    }

    float getBonus()
    {
        return this->bonus;
    }

    void setBonus(float bonus)
    {
        this->bonus = bonus;
    }

    void setEmployeeDetails()
    {
        Employee::setEmployeeDetails();

        cout << "Enter tasks completed (numeric): ";
        cin >> this->numTaskCompleted;

        if (numTaskCompleted >= 5)
            this->setBonus(10000.00f);
    }
};
```

softwareEngineer.h

```
#ifndef SOFTWARE_ENGINEER_H
#define SOFTWARE_ENGINEER_H
#include <string>
#include "employee.h"

using namespace std;

class SoftwareEngineer : public Employee
{
public:
    string getTitle();
    int getNumTaskCompleted();
    float getGrossSalary();
    float getBonus();
    void setBonus(float bonus);
    void setEmployeeDetails();
};
#endif
```

softwareEngineer.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "employee.h"

using namespace std;
class SoftwareEngineer : public Employee
{
private:
    int numTaskCompleted;
    float bonus;

public:
    string getTitle()
    {
        return "Engineer";
    }

    int getNumTaskCompleted()
    {
        return this->numTaskCompleted;
    }

    float getGrossSalary()
    {
        return this->getBaseSalary() + this->bonus;
    }

    float getBonus()
    {
        return this->bonus;
    }

    void setBonus(float bonus)
    {
        this->bonus = bonus;
    }

    void setEmployeeDetails()
    {
        Employee::setEmployeeDetails();

        cout << "Enter tasks completed (numeric): ";
        cin >> this->numTaskCompleted;

        if (numTaskCompleted >= 30)
            this->setBonus(5000.00f);
    }
};
```

program.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#include "employee.h"
#include "projectManager.h"
#include "softwareEngineer.h"

using namespace std;

Employee *_employees[4];

int main()
{
    for (int employeeIndex = 0; employeeIndex < 4; employeeIndex++)
    {
        Employee *CurrentEmployee = new Employee();
        CurrentEmployee->setEmployeeDetails();
        _employees[employeeIndex] = CurrentEmployee;
    }

    cout
        << setw(12) << "Employee" 
        << setw(5) << "Id"
        << setw(15) << "Employee"
        << setw(7) << "Task" 
        << setw(10) << "Base"
        << setw(13) << "Bonus"
        << setw(12) << "Gross" << endl;


    cout
        << setw(11) << "Title" 
        << setw(9) << "Number" 
        << setw(10) << "Name"
        << setw(12) << "Completed"
        << setw(8) << "Salary" 
        << setw(15) << "Entitlement"
        << setw(9) << "Salary" << endl;

    for (int employeeIndex = 0; employeeIndex < 4; employeeIndex++)
    {
        cout
            << setw(12) << _employees[employeeIndex]->getTitle()
            << setw(8)  << _employees[employeeIndex]->getId()
            << setw(13) << _employees[employeeIndex]->getName()  
            << setw(5)  << _employees[employeeIndex]->getNumTaskCompleted()
            << setw(13) << _employees[employeeIndex]->getBaseSalary()
            << setw(14) << _employees[employeeIndex]->getBonus()
            << setw(11) << _employees[employeeIndex]->getGrossSalary() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to debug this program, I get a message that there are build errors. These are the build errors I am getting.

> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int
>   __thiscall Employee::getId(void)" (?getId@Employee@@QAEHXZ) referenced
>   in function _main E:\C++
>   Assignments\assignment_7\assignment_7\program.obj assignment_7
>   Error 3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: float
>   __thiscall Employee::getBaseSalary(void)"
>   (?getBaseSalary@Employee@@QAEMXZ) referenced in function _main    E:\C++
>   Assignments\assignment_7\assignment_7\program.obj assignment_7
>   Error 2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator > __thiscall Employee::getName(void)"
>   (?getName@Employee@@QAE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)
>   referenced in function _main  E:\C++
>   Assignments\assignment_7\assignment_7\program.obj assignment_7
>   Error 8   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual
>   void __thiscall Employee::setEmployeeDetails(void)"
>   (?setEmployeeDetails@Employee@@UAEXXZ)    E:\C++
>   Assignments\assignment_7\assignment_7\program.obj assignment_7
>   Error 5   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int
>   __thiscall Employee::getNumTaskCompleted(void)"
>   (?getNumTaskCompleted@Employee@@UAEHXZ)   E:\C++
>   Assignments\assignment_7\assignment_7\program.obj assignment_7
>   Error 6   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual
>   float __thiscall Employee::getGrossSalary(void)"
>   (?getGrossSalary@Employee@@UAEMXZ)    E:\C++
>   Assignments\assignment_7\assignment_7\program.obj assignment_7
>   Error 7   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual
>   float __thiscall Employee::getBonus(void)"
>   (?getBonus@Employee@@UAEMXZ)  E:\C++

I have absolutely no idea what these errors mean. I've looked up the error codes, but couldn't gleam any information from them that would help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

Can anyone figure out what is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You seem to be defining the Employee class in both the header file and the source file.

Comment: Also ake sure that all the cpp files are actually in the project (look in the solution explorer window and make sure they're in the tree there) and not just open in the editor. I'd have expected some duplicate definition errors if they were.

Comment: "Unresolved external" means that one entity is referring to another entity outside the source file and the linker didn't find it.  Usually due to not putting all sources and libraries in the project or command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are linker errors ... after the complier finishes compiling your C++ code into object files, the linker then "links" these files together into an executable.  The linker though is saying it can't find the functions to link together that are being called in your `main` function.

A big problem I'm seeing right now, is that you've declared your classes inside your header files, but then you are re-declaring them inside your .cpp files.  That's going to cause problems.  **Declare** your classes in your header files (as you've done), but **define** your class functions in your .cpp files (you're re-doing the declaration in your .cpp files along with the definition).

Answer (score 1):

you are have multiple definition of `class Employee` in `employee.h` and `employee.cpp`.
Declare class Employee in employee.h and define its methods in employee.cpp

Answer (score 1):

As everyone else has said, you declared the same classes multiple times in different files.  As a rule of thumb, use header files (.h extension) for class declerations and source files (.cpp extension) for definitions.  Putting them in both places is both unnecessary and wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to include the class declaration in both the header and source files. Implementation should look like the following:

employee.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string Employee::getName()
{
    return this->name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head... try this:

employee.h:

```
#ifndef EMPLOYEE_H
#define EMPLOYEE_H

#include <string>

class Employee
{
private:
    std::string name;
    int id;
    float salary;

public:
    int empNumber;

    std::string getName();

    // Etc...

};
#endif
```

employee.cpp:

```
#include "employee.h"

std::string Employee::getName()
{
    return name;
}

// Etc...
```

BTW, avoid `using namespace` in headers - this can "pollute" unintentionally large body of code. Only do that in CPPs.